# Url redirect through IIS with query string

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I am trying to use iis url rewrite module to redirect the post requests with query string to some other url in the same domain. For example:

Original request url:
`https://www.example.com/ABC/DEF/GHI/JKL?q=<variableValue>&t=<variableValue>`

Redirected URL:
`https://www.example.com/DEF/GHI/JKL?q=<variableValue>&t=<variableValue>`

Request method is POST and it should be redirected using the same method with same request data and query string. I am not able to find an example. This is what I am trying to follow:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module

Comment: you could try this rule:`<rule name="query string redirect" stopProcessing="true"><match url="(.*)" />
<conditions>
<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www.domain1.com" />
<add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on" />
<add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="/ABC/DEF" />
<add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="q\=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\&amp;t=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)" /></conditions><action type="Redirect" url="http://www.domain1.com/DEF/GHI/JKL?q={C:1}&amp;t={C:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>`

Comment: Is your issue solved?
If your issue is solved then I suggest you to mark the helpful suggestion as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

you could try this rule

```
<rule name="query string redirect" stopProcessing="true"><match url="(.*)" />
 <conditions> 
<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www.domain1.com" /> 
<add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on" /> 
<add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="/ABC/DEF" />
<add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="q\=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\&amp;t=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)" />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="http://www.domain1.com/DEF/GHI/JKL?q={C:1}&amp;t={C:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```